# Why exactly doesn't PostgreSQL allow reordering the columns?

Tags: postgresql

Countless times, for example right now, I've had the need to change the order of columns in a table.

For example, when I improve the `CREATE TABLE` SQL code in my library, by adding a column somewhere in the table, and I then need to make my "live" table reflect those changes. When I add the new column, it's placed in the very end/"right", and refuses to let me specify where it should go.

While it's possible that this has little or no *performance* impact, it's very annoying to know that the column order differs between your "live" table and the one defined in the SQL code.

I've read the Stack Exchange questions about this, and asked the PG developers many times over the years. They inexplicably won't support reordering the columns, instead proposing ridiculous "solutions" such as dumping the entire database and loading it back in, or creating a separate "view", or many other bizarre workarounds which are just not practical, and in many cases even *worse* than having the wrong order.

I'm not asking how to do this, because it's clearly not possible. I'm just wondering *Why* it's not possible. I cannot imagine that there's a real technical challenge in reordering columns, but maybe there is? From the attitude/vibes I've picked up from the PG developers/community, this feels to me like one of those things which they could easily fix but just won't out of some philosophical reason.

What is the real reason? Would it really be so difficult for PG to simply swap some internal numbers so that the columns get the desired order? It really looks ugly to have two related columns far away from each other perpetually, as a punishment for me not thinking of that later column immediately when I initially created the table.

Comment: There is some background here https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20061219162504.GC21385@svana.org but this question deserves to be reopened.

Comment: This has been a debate I've heard many times. And each time it seems to be a head-butting between the "user"-facing realities and the bowels of database science. And thats where it stops - neither side accepting the other. What I don't understand is why there isn't a simple option to re-order the **display/output**. This would solve most everyone's issues (since most people who are asking for re-ordering don't actually need _bytes_ to be reordered - just the display). In my case, I need the columns to be reordered in a pg_dump... and of course I can't do that... for irrelevant reasons.

Comment: Whoever thinks this is "an opinion-based question" doesn't know what an OPINION is. ‍♂️

Answer (score 6):

There is a conceptual reason why this is very important, and there are reasons why nobody wants to implement it.

### Why is the column order irrelevant?

In SQL, the order of the columns in the table will only matter if you use

```
SELECT * FROM ...
```

And this is something that you should never use in code:

- If somebody adds or drops a column, the columns of your result set will suddenly change, and you won't get a database error, but the client application will probably gag on the now different data returned.
- If you join tables, you could suddenly end up with a result set where several columns have the same name. That can create confusion on the client side, and it will make a `CREATE VIEW` statement fail outright.
- Even if it does not cause one of the problems above, you will often end up fetching rows that you don't really need, which causes unnecessary traffic, processing and possible deTOASTing.

If you explicitly specify the columns in the `SELECT` list, the order of the columns in the table is irrelevant.

### Why could column order be relevant after all?

There are actually two small points where column order can make a difference:

- Alignment and padding:

  Each data type in PostgreSQL has an *alignment*. For example, an alignment of 8 bytes means that the datum may only be stored at a memory address that is a multiple of 8. Now if you have a `bigint` (alignment 8) immediately after a `smallint` (alignment 2), you could end up with up to 6 bytes of wasted "padding" space between those columns.
- Extracting data from a row:

  If you want to extract the 100th column from a row, you have to skip the first 99. That is more expensive than accessing the first column.

But in practice, performance and storage space optimizations like these don't have a large effect.

### Why has nobody implemented column reordering?

Since table rows are stored in the column order, changing that column order would mean to rewrite the whole table. So it wouldn't be substantially faster than export and import.

And there are already ways to work around the "shortcoming":

- Do it "on foot":

  ```
  BEGIN;
  CREATE TABLE tab_copy (col1 type1, col2 type2, ...);
  INSERT INTO tab_copy SELECT col12, col5, col1, ... FROM tab;
  DROP TABLE tab;
  ALTER TABLE tab_copy RENAME TO tab;
  COMMIT;
  ```

  This is an oversimplification: you'd also have to take care of foreign keys and other constraints.

  But essentially you can already reorder columns, it is just not as simple as it could be.
- You can use a view:

  ```
  CREATE VIEW newtab AS SELECT col12, col5, col1, ... FROM tab;
  ```

  Such views can be the target of `SELECT`, `INSERT` `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

[There have been serious efforts to implement this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20141209174146.GP1768%40alvh.no-ip.org), but the problem proves harder that it looks at first glance, and since there are workarounds, the pressure to see this through doesn't seem to be high enough.

Comment: No. You have to look from the view of the users, not the developers. Developers don't care about a table as long as it runs fine, but users have other considerations and ordering is a very important part. Consider a table that is randomly ordered so that you have the userId at the 25th column, the date at the 12th column, and the first 5 columns don't contain very important business data (but still have to be there). Now consider a table with exactly the same information, but all important columns are listed at front with a business logic that users understand.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey Right. That's why you use a view as user interface.

Comment: Bringing me out of retirement :) (1) `[using select *] is something that you should never use in code` -- maybe, but I usually don't care about ordering of columns from code, I care about CLI and ad-hoc queries, quick lookups. (2) The argument to `just use a view` would create unnecessary additional resources and clutter. (3) There are many reasons why this hasn't been implemented yet, I disagree with the ones you've provided. I'll add that RhomiumToad and others had considered altering the logical ordering pre-pandemic. I haven't followed up with the Postgres community since.

Comment: `nobody is willing to spend time and effort on something that is not very relevant and can already be done in some other way` I disagree with this entirely.  (1) relevance is subjective, but I believe we've hinted at this. (2) it can't easily be done in some other way, your example is effort and invites error.  How many tables have indices/constraints/fk-and-other dependencies? For something simple your example works, but when you want to change column order, its generally after a table has matured and has those additional complexities -- risk-averse developers aren't willing to scrap/recreate

Comment: @vol7ron I actually agree, and I have changed the last sentence. People have made serious attempts to implement this, yet I maintain that the feature is not important enough, and the existing workarounds are good enough.

Comment: So you're not concerned about the table's appearance when viewing it through tools like DataGrip? :( What are the workarounds available? Creating the schema manually or importing an SQL script? That's quite unfortunate.

Comment: I showed the options in my answer (e.g., use a view). No, I am not concerned with how the table looks in an interactive database client. If that is the relevant way for you to use the database, you should be using a spreadsheet application instead.

Comment: I agree that developers should have UX perspective. It's so weird that a table with many columns showing my newly created column at the end. FYI MySQL supports adding after and before a column. Downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

As someone with an outside perspective (because I primarily develop in Microsoft SQL Server, but have worked a little with PostgreSQL), don't worry about the column order, it has no material impact and is a subjective thing to be concerned about. Even though in Microsoft SQL Server you can technically re-order the columns of a Table, the same philosophy holds true in that community as well (that there's no need to be concerned with column order). Also, I believe (though I could be misremembering) changing the column order in a Table on Microsoft SQL Server results in that Table being dropped and recreated under the hood anyway.

The main reasons to not be concerned with column order (for Tables) is because that's a presentation layer responsibility, not a database responsibility. It is up to the consuming application in regards to what columns are used, shown, and in what order they're displayed. If you want concrete consistency and reusability, then the suggestion of using a View is the correct one (though dictating column order isn't the main purpose of a View, it is an included benefit for flexibility). This is a practical solution because there are other reasons you should use Views to be consumed by your applications / users as opposed to the base Tables anyway.

The other reason is, it is very rare that you're staring at your Table directly. If you're querying against a Table, you can choose which columns and in what order they're displayed in the result set. If you're using your Table in some functional / object oriented programming language in code, you're not looking at your Table directly either. Rather you should see the columns in some sort of "intellisense" of whatever IDE you're coding in, which means the columns will be listed in the order at the mercy of the IDE itself (and outside the control of the database).

At the end of the day, there is very little use case to have the ability to re-order your Tables' columns, especially since it has no bearing and there is no control by the database of how those columns will be ordered on the consuming end.